# Problem Spring Boot Admin Server not display Applications

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I'm trying use Spring Boot Admin Server but in the dashboard my application is not listed there.

What did I do, in my pom.xml I added the following dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/spring-boot-admin-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/spring-boot-admin-server-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/spring-boot-admin-starter-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my ServidorApplication Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAdminServer
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { JacksonAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ServidorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServidorApplication.class, args);System.err.println("Sem parametros de inicializacao");
    }

    GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new GsonHttpMessageConverter(new Gson());
    }
}
```

And in my application.properties:

```
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8084
management.security.enabled=false
```

But when I open the Spring Boot Admin dashboard I do not have any application.

[Print of my dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3xry.png)

can someone help me?

Comment: I discovered the problem, the problem was the URL I was used:

spring.boot.admin.url

Instead of:

spring.boot.admin.client.url

Answer (score 1):

Instead of admin.url use admin.client.url

spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8084